# Null or Empty Object parsing in Kotlinx.serialization

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization, kotlinx

How to parse both types of responses:

```
{
"x" : "some_string"
}
```

and

```
{
"x" : { } 
}
```

Into a data class that looks like:

```
@Serializable
data class SomeClass {
  
   @SerialName("x")
   val x : String?
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541201/parsing-empty-object-with-kotlinx-serialization

Comment: Unfortunately, it's similar but quite a different case

Answer (score 1):

This will only work by [writing a custom serializer](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#custom-serializers) which you apply to the `x` field.

`String` is a *primitive* (`JsonPrimitive`). `{}` is an *object* (`JsonObject`). You seem to be encoding `null` as an empty `JsonObject` here, and when the value is set, you encode it as a `JsonPrimitive`.

If this is a strict requirement, you need to write a custom serializer that translates an empty object to `null`, which should be fairly trivial. You probably also want the serialization to fail in case this object contains *any* keys.

However, the idiomatic way would be to simply encode this as `null`, in which case the default `kotlinx.serialization` serializer would work; it takes care of nullable types.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class Foo {
   @SerialName("bar")
   val bar: String? = null
}
```

I might be wrong though...

Source: [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1196)

Comment: This does work for normally nullable values. However, it still fails to parse the `{ }` as "null"

Comment: the solution above is correct for the String json, for the Json Object u need to add a secondary @SerialName("bar2") val bar2: ObjectX? = null

Comment: u cannot have 2 different types possible for the same key which is "x" in this case